# Connecting RS485 Device to computer in Modbus RTU

Tags: modbus, rs485

How to connect voltage monitoring meter with RS485 out, to a computer with Modbus RTU? Should I use a converter to RS232 and connect to serial COM port of computer? Should I use RS485 to USB converter to connect? Can I connect directly to serial COM port from A,B and Ground of RS485 using D9 connector pin? Then A,B and Ground to which pins of D9 in Modbus RTU? 
[ND20 pinout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrcXP.png)
[RS485 Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSGGJ.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Yes, you should use a RS485 to USB converter to connect the ND20 with your computer.
- At minimum you need to connect the A (sometimes called "-") and the B (or "+") line of your ND20 to the same lines of your RS485/USB adapter. Check your RS485/USB adapter manual for the pinout. Remember, the "A" line can alternatively be called "-", and "B" might be called "+". See here for [more RS485 application info](https://docklight.de/pdf/Docklight_Application_Note_RS422_485.pdf).
- Connecting GND is recommended, though in most situations it should work without.
- You need to know the baud rate / bits per second (9600? 19200?) the ND20 uses. You need to set this in the PC application.
- After having everything connected and ready to operate, you need use a PC application that accesses the RS485 converter ("COM" device on Window, e.g. "COM6"). The PC application needs to request measurement values and receive the results according to MODBUS RTU protocol specification. Our free [Docklight evaluation can help with MODBUS](http://docklight.de/manual/index.html?sendingmodbuscommandswithc.htm), but the most convenient solution is a small MODBUS master tool like this new freeware called [QModMaster](https://sourceforge.net/projects/qmodmaster/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Can small MODBUS masters like QModMaster provide view of energy values from ND20 as HMI graphically or do we need SCADA softwares for that along with configuring Modbus master tools? RS485 to USB or RS232 which converter is better for modbus? Any additional drivers needed? please help..

Comment: RS485 to USB is the right choice. For many standard devices Windows 7, 8 or 10 will automatically recognize the drivers. But it depends on your exact model and you need to check the documentation.

Comment: For graphical HMI you need some SCADA solution. But I wonder if the ND20 maybe comes with an example already (maybe for Labview?).

Comment: As an alternative to high-end SCADA solutions it's possible to use our own Docklight and Kickdrive software packages like seen in this blog post: https://docklightnews.blogspot.com/2015/08/docklight-scripting-v21-and-docklight.html . See the tablet UI with the microscope? This is basically a simple serial data connection (like MODBUS) and we can build an UI on top of this using our Kickdrive software and the great Qt Quick framework https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=odGXCqwtm1A . But this is really for the software developer and not as simple than maybe a Labview example for the ND20.

Comment: Thanks a lot Oliver ..  Much appreciated.

Comment: Arun, can you mark the answer as accepted answer then? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

option 1:  PC --> USB to RS232 --> RS232 to RS485 --> RS485 device

option 2:  PC --> USB to RS485 --> RS485 device

option 3:  PC --> RS232 to RS485 --> RS485 device

you need usb to rs485 / rs232 to rs485 convertors

As rs485 is floating, you may need ground to be connected for reliable comms

Answer (score -1):

You can connect using USB-RS485 converter. Don't know about other methods but It worked for me.
For details how to communicate from start to end have a look at this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X3RW-0e_PSI

This program worked windows & raspbian only difference was port name in both...

```
                    #THIS IS MY PYTHON PROGRAM 
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient as ModbusClient

client = ModbusClient(method='rtu', port='COM4', baudrate=2400, timeout=1)

client.connect()
read=client.read_holding_registers(address = 222 ,count =10,unit=1) 
//Address is register address e.g 30222, 
//and count is number of registers to read, 
//so it will read values of register 30222 to 30232
//unit is slave address, for 1 device leave it 1

data=read.registers[int(2)] #reading register 30223 
print(data) #printing value read in above line
```